# javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, tomcat, servlet-3

Na tentativa de acessar o método doPost, recebo um erro 500. Alguém pode me ajudar?

- Criei um projeto com o maven archetype webapp.
  -Tomcat 9

[image: Estrutura]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Servlet InserirCategoria]

[image: web.xml]

[image: POM]

Answer (score -1):

Esse erro normalmente acontece quando há alguma coisa errada com a conexão com o banco de dados. Porém, o servidor Tomcat apenas está te dando a mensagem que ele não está conseguindo inicializar a classe e logo na linha de baixo te dá o erro de conexão.

Eu percebi algo no seu código que você declarou no seu Servlet a notação @WebServelet e você tem um arquivo web.xml. Isso pode ser talvez o motivo do erro, tente limpar o arquivo web.xml, você já fez o mapeamento, deixe apenas o @WebServelet, e faça o teste.

Caso não funcionar, o seu servidor não está executando corretamente, tente reinstalar seu Tomcat, e provavelmente funcionará. Mas pelo que vi ainda assim pode te mostrar outro erro que é com a persistência, no entanto, tente fazer esses outros 2 primeiros passos que te falei, esses erros 500 e alguma coisa sempre acontece por erros do servidor.

Comment: Agora deixei meu arquivo web.xml na forma original, sem modificações. Após as modificaç~eos recebo o erro: 404 The requested resource [/crud-servlet-jsp/InserirCategoria] is not available

Comment: Então a notação @Webservelet não está fazendo o que deveria fazer. Faça um Servlet novo e utilize essa notação e tente acessar pela URL. Se não funcionar é ser servidor que está corrompido. Deverá reinstalar como tinha mencionado.

Comment: Se funcionar você já sabe o que fazer, passe os métodos tudo para esse novo servlet e exclua o antigo. Claro, use outro nome parecido, nunca o mesmo.